# Bluemix Service Instances Limit

Tags: service, ibm-cloud

I got a message that I exceeded the maximum number allowed for a particular service when creating a new application from a boilerplate on Bluemix. Is there a way to check the maximum number of the particular service instances i can create on Bluemix? The boilerplate I use has two services, Personality Insights and Monitoring and Analytics. I want to know what is the maximum permitted # of instances I can have for each of these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Bluemix UI navigate to your Dashboard and below each group you can see your limits, like 3/4 Services & APIs. See picture below for details.

[image]

Comment: It's a paid account, so the total # is not an issue. The question is about the maximum # of instances for a particular service.

Comment: what service specifically?

Comment: Personality Insights and Monitoring and Analytics

Comment: You can have only one instance of Monitoring and Analytics(M&A), but boilerplate application will automatically bind to an existing M&A if one is already created. There is no limit for Personality Insights, so I believe you reached the maximum number of services in your space. What is the specific error you are receiving? and what is the value for "Services & APIs" you have for your space? For example mine is 4/4 in the picture above, which means I reached my limit of 4 services.

Comment: how can I check the limit of services x space? I thought it is the total x org.

Comment: You are correct that a quota is defined for the organization, but when you are in the Dashboard UI you can see the Used/Limit for Services within your organization. If you look at the picture in my answer, the far left block that says "Services & APIs" has 2 numbers below it: the first number is the number of service instances and the second is the limit. For example I used 4 services of my total quota of 4.

Comment: cf org <org-name> will also list the quotas for the organization (including number of services instances allowed).

Answer (score 1):

If you're a "trial user", the max # of instances you can have is 10.  To remove this limit, convert your trial account to a pay account.  See the link below for more details:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/managingapps.html#tr_servicelimit

Comment: It's a paid account, so the total # is not an issue. The question is about the maximum # of instances for a particular service.